# Primefaces FileUpload call specify method with p:remoteCommand

Tags: file-upload, primefaces

In Primefaces 6.0 I need to process a file before it is uploaded and I try to call another method when I complete press browse button.  I try with remoteCommand but it doesn't work.

```
<p:fileUpload allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv|zip)$/"
        value="#{geoDataBean.file}" mode="simple" oncomplete="loadCountries();"
        update="countriesDropdownPanel">
</p:fileUpload>

<p:remoteCommand name="loadCountries" process="@this"
        action="#{geoDataBean.loadCountries()}"/>       

<h:panelGroup id="countriesDropdownPanel">
    <p:selectCheckboxMenu 
            widgetVar="countryCode" 
            id="countryCodeId"
            value="#{geoDataBean.selectedCountryCodes}"
            label="#{geoDataBean.label}" 
            multiple="true"
            panelStyle="width:198px">
        <p:ajax 
                event="toggleSelect" 
                update="countryCodeId"
                listener="#{geoDataBean.update}" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{geoDataBean.countryCodeList}" />
    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:commandButton value="Import" action="#{geoDataBean.importGeoData}" />
```

I need to process file before it will be imported because I need to see what countries exist in file to import them.

I use UploadedFile.

Comment: Could you not check after uploading and choose whether to save it or not?

Comment: I need to load it before my file it will be imported because I need to populate dropdown(checkBoxMeny)  with countries and only than when I select values from dropdown I do the import and save the content from file

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the function in onchange, instead of oncomplete

```
<p:fileUpload allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv|zip)$/"
                value="#{geoDataBean.file}" mode="simple" onchange="loadCountries();" update="countriesDropdownPanel">
                </p:fileUpload>
```

If you need to access the file in client side, you could also use the following jquery. This will work on browsers supporting input type file.

```
$("input[type=file]").on("change", function() {
        // Do your stuff with this.files
        loadCountries();
});
```

Comment: still doesn't trigger my method from Bean when I finish to put my file in browse ...

Comment: The jquery code works on https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml.